# Access query: Sort date logically, not alphabetically

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, jet

SQL for query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Format$([Client Accounting].[Closing Date],'mmmm') AS [Month], Count([Client Accounting].[Loan Number]) AS [DB Error #], Sum([Client Accounting].[Write Off]) AS [Write Off], Sum([Client Accounting].Refund) AS Refund
FROM [Client Accounting]
GROUP BY Format$([Client Accounting].[Closing Date],'mmmm'), Year([Client Accounting].[Closing Date])*12+DatePart('m',[Client Accounting].[Closing Date])-1
ORDER BY Format$([Client Accounting].[Closing Date],'mmmm'), Year([Client Accounting].[Closing Date])*12+DatePart('m',[Client Accounting].[Closing Date])-1;
```

Result as a datasheet is this:

[image: DB]

- The months represented above are: 12-14, 1-15, 2-15, 3-15
- The [Closing Date] field upon which the query is grouped/sorted is a Date/Time field with format m/d/yyyy (ex. 12/1/2014 or 3/26/2015)

As you can see, the months are sorted alphabetically, not logically. Is anyone able to advise how I can revise my SQL to have the query grouped/sorted by the date format *mm* (month in number format), but displayed in the datasheet/report as *mmmm* (month name in text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a field expression for the first day of the month to your `SELECT` list and `GROUP BY` clause.

```sql
DateSerial(Year([Closing Date]), Month([Closing Date]), 1) AS Month_Start
```

Then you can `ORDER BY` that calculated field.

If you don't want that field to appear in the query output, you can use it in a subquery --- the calculated field can then be used for `ORDER BY` but can be excluded from the parent query's `SELECT` list.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.Month,
    sub.[DB Error #],
    sub.[Write Off],
    sub.Refund
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DateSerial(Year(ca.[Closing Date]), Month(ca.[Closing Date]), 1) AS Month_Start,
        Format$(ca.[Closing Date],'mmmm') AS [Month],
        Count(ca.[Loan Number]) AS [DB Error #],
        Sum(ca.[Write Off]) AS [Write Off],
        Sum(ca.Refund) AS Refund
    FROM [Client Accounting] AS ca
    GROUP BY
        DateSerial(Year(ca.[Closing Date]), Month(ca.[Closing Date]), 1),
        Format$(ca.[Closing Date],'mmmm')
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY sub.Month_Start;
```

Notes:

1. `DISTINCTROW` is not useful in a `GROUP BY` query because the query's output rows are already unique by definition.
2. You could use another `Format` expression instead of the `DateSerial` expression I suggested, eg `Format(ca.[Closing Date], "yyyymm") AS YearMonth`

Comment: One day I hope to be an SQL ninja like you. Thank you for the help, it seems to produce the output I desire. Learning one step at a time :)

Comment: You're welcome.  That `Year(ca.[Closing Date])*12+DatePart('m',ca.[Closing Date])-1` baffled me.  But since you seemed happy with what it gives you, I figured we'd be OK without me understanding it.  :-)

Comment: That wasn't something I entered manually. I originally created the query using the Query Wizard and it was automatically generated as part of the Group By statement. I was equally baffled :)

Comment: Aha!  In that case, does the query work correctly if you remove that baffling piece?  (I suspect it's not useful.)

Comment: It seems to work the same without it, so I'll leave it out. One more question for you. How would I integrate a `HAVING` statement into this? I want to exclude records where ca.[Disputed] (which is a checkbox) = True

Comment: OK, I'll remove that "baffling piece" from my answer.  If you want `[Disputed]` evaluated by a `HAVING` clause you must `GROUP BY` it.  But I'm not sure that is necessary.  You can include that condition in a `WHERE` clause, which is pretty much the way you described in your comment: `WHERE  ca.[Disputed]  = True`

Comment: That's what I meant, doh! Thanks. By the way, your code is missing a comma after Month_Start.

Comment: Does the `WHERE` statement go in subquery or in the main query?

Comment: I get an error: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Format$(ca.[Closing Date],'mmmm') WHERE ca.[Disputed] = True

Am I missing a comma somewhere?

Comment: Put the `WHERE` clause after the `FROM` clause in the subquery.

Comment: If I want to further group the query by another table field (ca.[System]) and then create a different report for each [System], do I need to make a separate version of the query for each [System]?

I changed the clause to:
GROUP BY
        ca.[System],
        Format$(ca.[Closing Date], "yyyymm"),
        Format$(ca.[Closing Date],'mmmm')
So the group order is [System]->[Closing Date]. This results in each month showing up multiple times (each month per [System] as intended). Is there anyway to separate each [System] data on a report or should I just make a separate query for each [System]?

Comment: Please submit a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If your original query works except for the sorting, all you need is this to Group by the month-first:

```
SELECT 
    Format([Client Accounting].[Closing Date],'mmmm') AS [Month], 
    Count([Client Accounting].[Loan Number]) AS [DB Error #], 
    Sum([Client Accounting].[Write Off]) AS [Write Off], 
    Sum([Client Accounting].Refund) AS Refund
FROM 
    [Client Accounting]
GROUP BY 
    DateSerial(Year([Client Accounting].[Closing Date]), Month([Client Accounting].[Closing Date], 1),
    Format([Client Accounting].[Closing Date],'mmmm')
```